# Text Alignment in Print Document in Vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, vb.net-2010

I have tried the code below, but it didn't work for me.

```
Dim pen1 As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
Dim point1 As New Point(230, 420) 
Dim point2 As New Point(800, 420) 

e.Graphics.DrawString("This is to certify that", New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 120, 405)
e.Graphics.DrawString(TextBox33.Text + " " + TextBox39.Text + " " + TextBox38.Text + " " + TextBox37.Text, New Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 350, 400)
e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen1, point1, point2)
```

Comment: Nothing ever just doesn't work.  In every case, you have an expectation and an actual result.  You need to explain to us what your expectation is and how that actual result differs from it.  Is it really reasonable to expect us to know what you're trying to accomplish from code that doesn't actually accomplish it?  In short ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem rather than as few words as possible.

Comment: If you have an application with a control named `TextBox39` then you have a bad application.  ALWAYS provide descriptive names for everything unless it's burningly obvious what it does from context, e.g. `i` for a loop counter.

Comment: You should always use `&` rather than `+` to concatenate strings and you should never concatenate more than two or three strings either.  You should acquaint yourself with the `String.Format` method and, in VB 2015 and later, string interpolation, e.g. `$"{TextBox33.Text} {TextBox39.Text} {TextBox38.Text} {TextBox37.Text}"`.